# Request/Response works with primitives but not with Objects

Tags: c#, masstransit

I have a Request-Response message setup using the following;

```
public class StatusUpdateRequestConsumer : IConsumer<StatusUpdateRequest>
{
    private readonly IWmiService _wmiService;

    public StatusUpdateRequestConsumer(IWmiService wmiService)
    {
        _wmiService = wmiService;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<StatusUpdateRequest> context)
    {
        var bios = _wmiService.GetBios();         

        await context.RespondAsync<StatusUpdateResponse>(
            new StatusUpdateResponse()
            {
                // This line works fine and message is sent back instantly
                Message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bios) //,
                // Sending the actual object instead of a JSON 
                // representation as so doesn't work
                // Bios = bios           
            }
        );
    }
}
```

When sending a String by doing JsonConvert.SerializeObject() on my object and sending the result - the message is received instantly and all works good.

When I try to send the message with the actual object itsself (bios in the above example), the response in never recieved but no exceptions or errors are thrown.

I thought MassTransit would just serialize to JSON in the same manner before sending the message, anyone have any ideas why this wouldn't work - or any other troubleshooting I can apply to try to find the error being reported if any?

I tried adding a   `IConsumer<Fault<StatusUpdateRequest>>` and   `IConsumer<Fault<StatusUpdateResponse>>` but they were not called.

Answer (score 0):

Using internal system types in message contracts isn't always the best choice, typically because of things you might be seeing trying to serialize the BIOS object. It's recommended to map that object into something that is defined by the message contract, versus relying on the internal system type.

That said, the message may be sending, but failing to deserialize on the receiving end, due to a missing assembly reference or something - again, why it's best not to use system types for serialization. You may be able to serialize it, but it's failing on the deserialize, with generates a ReceiveFault, or perhaps just a `Fault` is published, versus a `Fault<StatusUpdateResponse>` since it can't deserialize that type.